# Como faço para contabilizar valores de um array?

Tags: javascript

parece ser uma pergunta meio boba, mas como faço para contabilizar os valores do array e mostrar a fração de numeros positivos, negativos e zeros existentes, por exemplo: [1,3,0, -1] e retorna [0.50,0.25,0.25]? 
Eu fiz um for e if, mas ainda continuo com essa dúvida.

Obrigado

Comment: kd seu código? poste pra tentarmos melhorá-lo ;)

Comment: Podes explicar melhor o que pretendes e com exemplos? Qual é a relação entre essas arrays?

Comment: @Sergio eu tenho uma função na qual vou receber x array e nele eu preciso contabilizar a quantidade de numero positivos, negativos e 0 que possui, e com isso retornar um outro array com a porcentagem de numeros, por exemplo, numerosX([1, 2, 0, -1]) deveria retornar [0.5, 0.25, 0.25], devido a que há 50% de positivos, 25% de zeros, e 25% de negativos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viva!

Penso que seja isto que você quer:

```js
function percentagens(arrayNumeros) {
  var countPositivos = 0,
      countNegativos = 0,
      countNeutros = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < arrayNumeros.length; i++) { 
    if (arrayNumeros[i] > 0) {
      countPositivos++;
    } else if (numeros[i] < 0) {
      countNegativos++;
    } else {
      countNeutros++;
    }
  }

  return [(countPositivos / arrayNumeros.length),(countNegativos / arrayNumeros.length),(countNeutros / arrayNumeros.length)];
}

var numeros = [1,3,0, -1];
alert(percentagens(numeros));
```